# I am looking for the website of definite integral.

Tags: definite-integrals, soft-question

In these days, I often calculate definite integrals many time, like the Gamma function. So I am looking for some websites containing definite integrals.

Does anyone know such websites?

Comment: You mean for evaluating integrals? You can try Wolfram Alpha, for example.

Comment: i know wolfram alpha , but it is not sufficient

Comment: if possible, i want closed form of them

Comment: Try a book containing a list of integrals, e.g.  this is a good one: https://www.elsevier.com/books/table-of-integrals-series-and-products/jeffrey/978-0-08-047111-2 - I think this one is accessible online if you have library access etc, e.g. via ScienceDirect.

Comment: thanks but i dont have access...

Comment: If Wolfram Alpha is not sufficient, I am afraid no site in the world can help you.

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/ has many definite integrals in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to learn and better understand some of the various techniques that can be used to evaluate definite integrals, particularly improper integrals, the following two texts come highly recommended. Each text covers the various standard techniques that can be used to evaluate definite integrals together we a collect of exercise sets to be worked on by the reader. The texts are:

1. *Improper Riemann integrals* by Ioannis M. Roussos (CRC Press, 2014).
2. *Integral evaluations using the gamma and beta functions and elliptical integrals in engineering: A self-study approach* by C. C. Maican (International Press, 2005).

Comment: are they on the web?

Comment: As I said in my post, these are texts not websites.